# Error from the simple project to connect MySQL with Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I wrote very simple mysql connection code. but it shows error logs:

```
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/Volumes/Data/Study/mysql-test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/Volumes/Data/Study/mysql-test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:130:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Volumes/Data/Study/mysql-test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (/Volumes/Data/Study/mysql-test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (/Volumes/Data/Study/mysql-test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Data/Study/mysql-test/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Volumes/Data/Study/mysql-test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Volumes/Data/Study/mysql-test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Volumes/Data/Study/mysql-test/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Data/Study/mysql-test/app.js:8:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
```

I installed mysql and following are package.json and app.js

```
{
  "name": "mysql-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql": "^2.15.0"
  }
}
```

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'mypassword',
  database: 'test',
});
connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
      throw err;
  }
  console.log('Connected!');
});
```

In phpMyAdmin, test database has full permission with root user.( attached screenshot)
Also I tried to add port number: 3306.
And tried to connect the "test" database with terminal, it works.

The project is very simple tutorial code that have only 2 files (app.js and package.json), db user name and password is working with terminal and db permission seems have full accesses.
What is the problem ? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVzJK.png)

Comment: It looks ok to me. How are you connecting to the database in the terminal? Using the mysql client? What version of mysql?

Comment: The password is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct.
In my phpmyadmin, i have two lines for permissions on databases
root    127.0.0.1   global  ALL PRIVILEGES
and 
root    localhost   global ALL PRIVILEGES

on your screenshoot you have only :
root localhost

and in your error :
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'**127.0.0.1'**

Try to create an Mysql user root@127.0.0.1 and grant him privileges on database test.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you very much.
It is working with your solution.**
I have "root/localhost" user in the users list, but added new user "root/127.0.0.1".
I am still not understanding why "localhost" is different with "127.0.0.1". but anyways the problem was solved.